# How can I populate this 2d array with values from a char array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

So I have a grid that is 6 by 7

```
char[][] grid = new char[6][7];
```

And is populated with blank spaces using this loop:

```
for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
            grid[row][col] = ' ';
        }
    }
```

I also have a char[] array that holds 'A's 'B's and blank spaces. For example ch[0] = B, ch[1] = A, ch[8] = " ".

And I am simply trying to populate each slot of the 2d array 'grid' with the contents of the char array one at a time.

I tried to use the same for loop with some changes to populate the grid but when I run it only populates the top row of my grid and I'm not sure why. I have tried to move the i++, and change the for loop parameters but nothing is working and I need help. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
            int i = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
                    grid[row][col] = ch[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

If it helps to know I am getting the contents of ch[] from a .csv file and storing it in a char array. When I run this code as is, it perfectly populates the top row of my grid (first row) but then it does not do anything to the remaining rows.

I don't want to change the data types of anything, I know I can get this too work I just need some help.

Comment: I assume you want each row in the 2D array to have the same values as char array.  In that case, remove i and replace ```grid[row][col] = ch[i];``` with ```grid[row][col] = ch[col];```

Comment: That doesnt work, what I want is the first row of the 2d array to fill with the same values as ch[], than once that row is full and its on the next row of the 2d array, to simply continue to add the values in ch[] from where it left off on the previous row.

Comment: Something else I just realized is if I change my code from grid[row][col] = ch[i] and just change the ch[i] to 'A' for example it populates the whole grid with A, so its something wrong with ch[i] I think

Comment: The length of ch[] is equal to row*height of grid?  If not, do you want it to loop around?